# How to access specific object attributes after creating multiple objects? Python

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to practice Python coding by creating an OO code that manages a movie store. The code that I've done is working fine and doing what I want, BUT in my code the object Movie has 2 attributes (name, ncopies), I'm using a list to correlate each movie *name* with its own *ncopies* attributes, I would like to access those attributes by using Objected Oriented programming like *something.name* and that gives me the name of the movie, instead of having to maintain 2 correlated lists and have to get the indexes every time I want to get an attribute, any thoughts?

```
class Movie:
    global lista_names 
    global lista_ncopies
    lista_names = [] #list of movie names
    lista_ncopies = []  #list of movie copies

    def __init__(self, name, ncopies):#keeps movie name and ncopies with same index
        self.name = name 
        self.ncopies = ncopies
        lista_names.append(self.name) #append movie name to the list
        lista_ncopies.append(self.ncopies) #append ncopies to the list

def showNumberOfCopies():
    pesquisa = input("digite o nome")#variable receives the movie name
    if pesquisa in lista_names: #checks if its in the movie names list
        indice = lista_names.index(pesquisa) #gets its index
        print ("num de copias de",pesquisa,"eh ",lista_ncopies[indice])        
    menu()   
def addMovie():
    name = input("digite o titulo") #get name of the movie
    ncopies = int(input("digite o numero de copias"))#get num of copies
    movie1 = Movie(name, ncopies) #create object 
    menu()

def updateMovie():
    pesquisa = input("type the name of the movie ")
    if pesquisa in lista_names: #checks if movie is in lista_names
        indice = lista_names.index(pesquisa) #gets the index
    else:
        opcao = input("o filme desejado nao esta em nosso acervo, deseja atualizar outro filme? s/n") #just in case the movie is not in lista_names
        if opcao == 's' or opcao == 'S':
            updateMovie()
        else:
            menu()
    opcao2 = input("update ncopies or movie name? type ncopias/nome")
    if opcao2 == 'ncopias':
        print ("the number of copies is: ",lista_ncopies[indice]) 
        ncopies_new = int(input("digite o numero de copias novo"))
        lista_ncopies[indice] = ncopies_new
        menu()
    elif opcao2 == 'nome':
        print ("name of the movie is",lista_names[indice])
        name_new = input("type the new name")
        lista_names[indice] = name_new
        print (lista_names)
        menu()            

def menu():
    opcao =  int(input('1-add filme\n2-search filme\n3-update\n4-exit'))
    if opcao == 1:
        addMovie()
    elif opcao == 2:
        showNumberOfCopies()
    elif opcao == 3:
        updateMovie()
    elif opcao == 4:
        quit    
    else:
        menu()        


menu()
```

Comment: Would you consider using a dict object ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, i think that would work fine but what if I wanted to  put some more attributes in the Movie class like (name, year, ncopies, genre, etc), you solved my problem but thats not exactly what I'm trying to do =)

Comment: you can use something like {name : {<another dict mapping data }}

Comment: will try that, thank you sir =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could instead use a dict object() that maps the movie name to ncopies. Something like

```
class Movie:
    global m_dict 
    m_dict = {} #dict object

    def __init__(self, name, ncopies):#keeps movie name and ncopies with same index
        self.m_dict = m_dict 
        m_dict[name] = ncopies #The other way if you wish
```

And then you can access like `M.m_dict` and look up the dict for the name of the movies mapped to the number of copies